# How to write a trigger in Oracle which will log info if any CREATE, DROP, ALTER, UPDATE, DELETE is performed?

Tags: oracle, triggers

Primarily, what I wanted to do is to write a trigger which will log in a table the following -

```
username
modification (like - CREATE ALTER DROP UPDATE DELETE)
datetime (when it happend)
```

If any of the following things happen -CREATE ALTER DROP UPDATE DELETE then the trigger will log the information.

Is it even possible to do so?

I came up with table level triggers which will do for INSERT UPDATE DELETE for particular table.

But, I do need all of the them in schema level for any object.

If not, at-least for any table.

Answer (score 2):

This works on Oracle 11g.  I can't remember where I got it from

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER <YourSchema>.audit_ddl_trg
   AFTER DDL
   ON SCHEMA
BEGIN
   IF (ora_sysevent = 'TRUNCATE')
   THEN
      NULL;                                    -- I do not care about truncate
   ELSE
      INSERT INTO <YourSchema>.audit_ddl (d,
                                   osuser,
                                   current_user,
                                   HOST,
                                   terminal,
                                   owner,
                                   TYPE,
                                   name,
                                   sysevent)
        VALUES   (SYSDATE,
                  SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'OS_USER'),
                  SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER'),
                  SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'HOST'),
                  SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'TERMINAL'),
                  ora_dict_obj_owner,
                  ora_dict_obj_type,
                  ora_dict_obj_name,
                  ora_sysevent);
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Do recall that if declared ON SCHEMA then it only fires if someone logged in as the schema performs the DDL. To get all actions within the schema you need to declare it ON DATABASE then check the schema of the DDL target is the correct one. Relevant discussion is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640317/oracle-trigger-on-schema-not-being-triggered-by-other-users-besides-the-schema-o

Comment: This is awesome, but for an UPDATE or DELETE it does not work.. I need to log all these events -CREATE ALTER DROP UPDATE DELETE

Comment: For DML statements like that you should use auditing as it lets you record these operations on an object  by object.  Why not ask another question about Oracle auditing or search?